# Map State name using state code Using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have 2 csv file. The CSV file on which i am performing is having Some values as state codes and some as state Names, I want to replace the state code with the state names.

**CSV 1**

```
state

Assam
Goa
06
Kerala
12
```

**CSV 2**

```
S.No  state_name  state_code

1      Karnataka     06
2      Mizoram       12
3      Meghalaya     15
```

OUTPUT required in CSV 1:

```
state
Assam
Goa
Karnataka
Kerala
Mizoram
```

What i have tried so far:

```
df= pd.read_csv("csv1.csv")


data1 = pd.read_csv("csv1.csv")

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for index_config, row_config in data1.iterrows():
        if row['state'] == row_config['']:
            df['state'] = row_config['State']
```

How i can map the state_name from CSV 2 in place of state code values in state column of CSV 1

Comment: `df['state'] = df['state'].replace(data1.set_index('state_code')['state_name'])`.

Comment: My answer was evolving to be exactly what @QuangHoang shows above... so no point in duplicating the information.

Answer (score 1):

Let us first create a mapping `dictionary`, and then use `replace` method for the first dataframe(`df1`):

```
#df1 is for CSV1 and df2 is for CSV2 file
mapping = dict(zip(df2['state_code'], df2['state_name']))
#print(mapping)
#{'06': 'Karnataka', '12': 'Mizoram', '15': 'Meghalaya'}

df1['state'] = df1.state.replace(mapping)
```

Output:

```
    state
0   Assam
1   Goa
2   Karnataka
3   Kerala
4   Mizoram
```

Comment: Its working up to print(mapping) but the last statement is not working.

Comment: I guess the problem might be with `format` of `state_code` column. add `df2['state_code'] = df2['state_code'].astype(str)` to the beginning of my solution. and Then apply my answer. Please let me know how it performs.